# How to add different styles to span tag based on its content using react or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i have a span element like below, and i want to change the count_variable color based on its value.

```
render = () => {
    const count_variable = this.get_count(); //this function returns an 
    //integer variable
    return (
        <div>
            <span>counter</span>
            <span>{count_variable}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

and the output would look like below for example,
       count 0

Now when this count_variable

```
value is 0 i want its color to be red
value is 1 want its color to be blue
value is greater than 1 its color to be green
```

How can i do it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the help of **ternary operator**

```
render = () => {
    const count_variable = this.get_count();
    return (
      <span>counter</span>
      <span style={{ color: count_variable === 0 ? 'red' : count_variable === 1 ? 'blue' : 'green' }}>
        {count_variable}
      </span >
 )    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render = () => {
  const count = this.get_count(); //this function returns an 
  return (
      <div>
          <span>counter</span>
          <span style={color: count === 0 ? 'red' : count === 1 ? 'blue' : 'green'}>{count}</span>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
render = () => {
    const count_variable = this.get_count(); //this function returns an
    //integer variable

    let color = "";
    switch(count_variable) {
        case 0: color = "red"; break;
        case 1: color = "blue"; break;
        case 2: color = "green"; break;
        // Add more cases here for more colors
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <span>counter</span>
            <span style={{color: color}}>{count_variable}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Ternary operators can be quite confusing when you come back to the code after some time, which is why I'm using switch statement. It will allow you to add more cases later on easily, as well as provide default case if the nothing matched.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, this is a good read https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

```
let divStyle = {
  color: 'blue'
};

render = () => {
    const count_variable = this.get_count(); //this function returns an 
    //integer variable
    if (count_variable===0)
        divStyle.color = 'red'
    else if (count_variable===1)
        divstyle.color = 'blue'
    else
        divstyle.color = 'green'
    return (
        <div>
            <span>counter</span>
            <span style={divStyle}>{count_variable}</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```